# How do you extrude a shape without outer faces and edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

In Sketchup, if have a shape that I want to cut a section out of, I can use the pencil tool to draw an area and then extrude the area down (using the push / pull tool). The outside edges are removed:

[image: Sketchup: Draw in pencil tool]
[image: Sketchup: Push down]

In Blender, I'm trying to do the same thing but it isn't working in the same way. I used the Knife tool to draw the area I want to remove and extrude down, but the outer edges are still remaining:

[image: Blender: draw shape with Knife tool]
[image: Blender: extrude down]

I haven't yet figured out a way to manipulate the mesh to get the desired result after this extrusion.

Is there a faster / better way to do this in Blender? Is there a tool that behaves similarly to Sketchup's push / pull tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: As Nicola Sap says it's now available in Blender, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Manifold*.

You need an addon to do that with the previous version, *Blender Destructive Extrude*:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=beZau_wpR-U

https://gumroad.com/l/cQjUX

or you need to delete and fill some faces, or try to extrapolate before modeling.

Comment: The version of the addon linked from the YouTube video (on GitHub) doesn't appear to work properly but version 0.8.9 from the gum road link worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: See also my more recent answer: this feature has been added to Blender (`master`) and will be available as a stable tool from August 2020

Comment: ok, I'm editing my answer

Answer (score 8):

This feature has just been added to Blender.

It will be available from version 2.90(https://builder.blender.org/download/).

It's called "**Extrude Manifold**" and is located in the toolbox <kbd>T</kbd>, under the "*Extrude*" dropdown, Or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

[image]

<sup>*↑ Here I'm using Face select mode (<kbd>3</kbd>) but it works in vertex select too*</sup>

Comment: That tool is new to me and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this feature is lacking in blender. You've got two options here - move all the faces down and only extrude the ones you want higher upwards. This would work fine in your case.

[image: Before the extrusion]

[image: Afterwards]

Alternatively you can delete the faces you don't want - this option is for when it doesn't work out with the first method.